# Implementing an Enum Array to String Array TypeConverter in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enums, typeconverter

In C# or VB.NET, under WinForms, I have a property that returns an array of a enum. See an example:

```
public enum TestEnum: int {
    Name1 = 0,
    Name2 = 1,
    Name3 = 2
} // Note that the enum does not apply for the [Flags] attribute.

public TestEnum[] TestProperty {get; set;} = 
    new[] {TestEnum.Name1, TestEnum.Name2, TestEnum.Name3};
```

By default, a [PropertyGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid?view=netframework-4.7.2) will show the values as int[], like: {0, 1, 2} instead of the enumeration value names, like: {"Name1", "Name2", "Name2"}, which is the visual representation that I would like to acchieve...

So, I would like to design a [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) that could be able to return a string array with the value names, and apply it like this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumArrayToStringArrayTypeConverter))]
public TestEnum[] TestProperty {get; set;} = 
    new[] {TestEnum.Name1, TestEnum.Name2, TestEnum.Name3};
```

In other words, If my property is represented like this in a PropertyGrid:

[image]

I would like to have this:

[image]

---

The biggest problem I'm facing is trying to retrieve the type of the enum from the custom type-converter class, to be able get the value names of that enum. I only can get the primitive data type of the array (like: int[], uint16[], etc)...

```
public class EnumArrayToStringArrayTypeConverter : TypeConverter {
    // ...

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                                     CultureInfo culture, 
                                     object value, 
                                     Type destinationType) {

        if (destinationType == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destinationType));
        }

        try {
            // This will return the array-type for the 
            // primitive data type of the declared enum, 
            // such as int[], uint16[], etc.
            Type t = value.GetType(); 

            // I'm stuck at this point. 
            // ...

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        return null;
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

Please take into account that I'm asking for a reusable solution that can work for any kind of enum. And, my enum in this example does not have the [Flags] attribute applied, but a solution should care about enums having it, so, If a enum item of the enum array is a enum that has various flags, those flags (the value names) should be concatenated for example using **string.join()**.

Comment: For the first problem, how about `Enum.GetNames(Type)`

Comment: @blins yes... but for being able to do that, firstly I need to determine the enum type (that is the first, main problem). Thanks for comment.

Comment: In your example, the array contains the values 3, 4 and 10 which are not valid values of the enumeration (0,1,2). Maybe this is already the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PropertyGrid` does already show the names for the `enum` values. It can even handle `[Flags]` correctly. See the sample below using a form with a default PropertyGrid and a default button and nothing else.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum TestEnum : int
    {
        Name1 = 0,
        Name2 = 1,
        Name3 = 2
    } 

    public class TestObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Hello World";
        public TestEnum[] TestProperty { get; set; } =
            new[] { TestEnum.Name1, TestEnum.Name2 | TestEnum.Name3, TestEnum.Name3 };
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestObject o = new TestObject();
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = o;
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

Please supply some example code that can reproduce that the enum names are not shown in the PropertyGrid. You must be doing something wrong in the first place.

Comment: many thanks for the tip. After debugging a little bit I discovered which was the problem (I published an answer to explain it). In short the problem was the way I was assigning the value of my property, but not sure why the property grid behavior radically changed for doing that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @NineBerry in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816270/1248295), the **PropertyGrid** does already show the names for the enum values. However, I discovered that exists a strange circumstance on wich it will not do it...

Since my original source-code is written in VB.NET, I'll put VB.NET sample codes to reproduce the issue.

The thing is that I was getting a value from a instance of a WMI class (specifically: [Win32_DiskDrive.Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive)), which returns an object that needs to be casted to a uint16 array. Then, I was casting that resulting uint16 array to my type of enum. To simplify things, I will not show WMI code, but an object that represents what I was getting from WMI...

```
Dim wmiValue As Object = {1US, 2US, 3US}
Dim castedValue As UShort() = DirectCast(wmiValue, UShort())
TestProperty = DirectCast(castedValue, TestEnum())
```

So, when doing that type-casting, and thanks to @NineBerry answer, I discovered that for some reason the default type converter of **TestProperty** goes wrong and the **PropertyGrid** shows uint16 values instead of the enum value-names.

( Note that using **DirectCast()** or **CType()** in VB.NET, it didn't changed the **PropertyGrid** behavior. )

To fix the error, I ended using **Array.ConvertAll()**, and then the **PropertyGrid** properly shows the value-names...

```
Dim wmiValue As Object = {1US, 2US, 3US}
Dim castedValue As UShort() = DirectCast(wmiValue, UShort())
TestProperty = Array.ConvertAll(castedValue,
                                Function(value As UShort)
                                    Return DirectCast(value, TestEnum)
                                End Function)
```